Why CLI influx backup does not work on my Raspberry Pi?
I have installed influxDB 2.7.6, and the shell version 1.6.7-rc0. When I try to run a backup, I get an error:
influx backup
    unknown arguments: backup

Is there any other extension or add-on I have to install in order that I can execute a backup by the command line?
Thx.
